# HTTP2_Plain in node-http2 module is not working?

Tags: http2

I want to create a http2 server using [node-http2](https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2) module without TLS. My code is as follows:

```
http2 = require('http2');
const bunyan = require('bunyan');

var log = bunyan.createLogger({name: "HTTP2 server without TLS!"});

var options = {
    log: log
}

var server = http2.raw.createServer(options, function(request, response) {
    console.log("Receiving HTTP2 request!");
    // response.writeHead(200);
    response.end('Hello world from HTTP2!');
});

server.listen(8000);
```

However, it does not work. When connecting to this server from chrome, it shows downloading something. When I closed the server, the downloading is finished with blank file (26 bytes).

Does anyone know what is wrong here? Do I need to configure the browser? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome and all other browsers only support HTTP/2 over TLS (h2) and not plain HTTP/2 (h2c). So your browser does not understand what is returned from the server and apparently node-http2 does not send a proper error response when it receives a non-http2 request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems not just from the browser. Using [curl] [curllink](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html) that supports http2 over an http:// URL does not working either. Following is the output from the curl:

```
$ curl -I --http2 http://54.208.83.136:8000/ -v -k
*   Trying 54.208.83.136...
* Connected to 54.208.83.136 (54.208.83.136) port 8000 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 54.208.83.136:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.1
> Accept: */*
> Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
> Upgrade: h2c
> HTTP2-Settings: AAMAAABkAAQAAP__
>
```

As we see from the curl output. It sends http/1.1 Upgrade request with proper headers set as it supposed to do according to the [http2 rfc] [rfclink](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540).

On the server side, the logs were very long, so I present here only the content of msg in the relevant three logs.

```
New incoming HTTP/2 connection

Client connection header prelude does not match

PROTOCOL ERROR, Fatal error, closing connection
```

So basically the server closed the connection because the client connection header prelude does not match. By checking the code, I figured out the error was originated from the readPrelude function of [endpoint.js] [endpointlink](https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2/blob/master/lib/protocol/endpoint.js). It is a function to read the client header, but I don't know what is wrong in the client header :(.

Thus maybe I can say the node-http2 module does not support http2 over plaintext.

**Update**: it turns out that I was wrong. The node-http2 module do support http2 over plaintext with direct connecting, it **does not support** HTTP/2 server with Upgrade from HTTP/1.1. The problem resulted from the client side using Upgrade mechanism to connect to the server not supporting Upgrade. Using nghttp client to connect sever with prior knowledge works as follows.

```
$ nghttp http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
Hello world from HTTP2!
```

nghttpd server also supports HTTP2 without TLS, even though it does not support HTTP Upgrade.

```
$ nghttpd -d /Documents/Proxy 8080 --no-tls -v
```

So I highly suggest to use nghttp when you want to test HTTP2 without TLS.